# How to write a test case of custom save method of an interface

Tags: java, sql, spring, junit, spring-data-jpa

While writing jUnit for my project i have came across a peace of code for which i have no idea how to proceed which the jUnit.
Below is the code for which i am trying to write jUnit.

```
@Repository
public interface PrescriptionRepository extends CrudRepository<Prescription, 
Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "insert ignore into prescription (dose_id,med_id) values (:doseId,:medId)", nativeQuery = true)
    public void savePrescription(@Param("doseId") int doseId, @Param("medId") int medId);

    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You don't test interfaces, you test their implementation.

Comment: Do you use Spring or Spring Boot ?

Comment: @davidxxx Spring Boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the behavior of the generated class of this interface by Spring you need first of the Spring container.
Then if you want to write an unit test (and not a full integration test), you need to use an embedded DB (H2 for example).
Generally you don't want to load the whole spring container but only the part for the JPA Spring components.
If you use Spring Boot, the slice testing feature [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) will be very helpful.

Then concerning the testing part, it is rather simple : in your unit test invoke your save method and then use repository method to retrieve the inserted data.
And at last assert that your get the expected object.

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.*;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.*;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class PrescriptionRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private PrescriptionRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void savePrescription() throws Exception { 
        this.repository.savePrescription(...);
        Prescription actualPrescription = em.findById(...); 
        assertThat(actualPrescrition.getDoseId()).isEqualTo("doseId...");
        assertThat(actualPrescrition.getMedId()).isEqualTo("medId...");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is: what would you like to test exactly?

Let's assume that you want to test if it's inserted into the database correctly, then after calling the function you want to test you should check the instance in the database if it exists or not. THe easyest way to call

`List<Prescription> prescriptions = prescriptionRepository.findAll();`

Then check if there is any

`assertTrue(prescriptions.size() == 1);`

And then get the first element of it, and check whatever you want

`Prescription prescription = prescriptions.get(0);`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Since Prescription is a List assertion should be greater or equal to 1